# Rust lifetime issue when dealing with `Into` generics

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

*Thanks for correcting my way of asking questions. I have made several revisions to make the code compilable.*

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Brace {
    x: i32,
}

impl Brace {
    fn transform(&self, n: i32) -> Devil {
        Devil {
            hp: self.x + n,
            weapon: None,
        }
    }
}

struct Bar<'a> {
    tasty: &'a str,
}

struct Foo<'a, B>
    where B: 'a + Into<Bar<'a>>
{
    brace: Brace,
    buz: Option<B>, // buz is of generic type B, and is able to be turned into bar.
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a B>, // A marker that is used to resolve 'unused lifetime parameter a'
}

impl<'a, B: Into<Bar<'a>>> Foo<'a, B> {
    fn transform_and_arm(self) {
        // line B
        let brace1: Brace = self.brace;
        let mut devil: Devil = brace1.transform(12345); // line A
        let buz = self.buz.unwrap();
        // Before this line, it passes the compiler.
        // Uncommenting the following line causes compiler to argue that the brace1 at line A doesn't live long enough. It says that borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at line B, but the borrowed value only lives until line C.
        // devil = devil.arm(buz);
        // Although adding the above line fails, making the weapon directly won't cause the compiler to complain.
        // Uncommenting the following line passes compiler.
        // let weapon = buz.into();

        // The compiler stops the devil from arming itself before I even try to write the following line.
        // devil.slay_the_world();
    } // line C
}

struct Devil<'a> {
    hp: i32,
    weapon: Option<Bar<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Devil<'a> {
    fn arm<B: Into<Bar<'a>>>(mut self, biu: B) -> Devil<'a> {
        self.weapon = Some(biu.into());
        self
    }

    fn slay_the_world(self) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

The `transform_and_arm()` method is designed to consume an instance of `Foo` by taking away `brace` and `buz`. It calls `brace.transform()` to make `brace` a `Devil`. It strengthens the devil by feeding the devil with `buz.unwrap()`.

The problem is that, calling `let weapon = buz.into();` is legal, while calling `devil = devil.arm(buz);` causes a lifetime problem.

It seems that the problem is much related with the lifetime. If there were no 'a for Devil, then all these problems would vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: *My previous answer did not explain the problem very well. Here is another attempt.*

You are having this problem because `transform` is flawed. To find out why, let's see what lifetimes the compiler has inferred for `transform`:

```
fn transform<'a>(&'a self, n: i32) -> Devil<'a>
```

We can see that the compiler has decided to give the returned `Devil` the same lifetime as the reference to `self` that is passed to the function.

Now, let's look at `Devil`:

```
struct Devil<'a> {
    hp: i32,
    weapon: Option<Bar<'a>>,
}
```

We can see that `Devil`'s lifetime parameter is associated with its `weapon`.

Looking back at `transform`, however...

```
fn transform<'a>(&'a self, n: i32) -> Devil<'a> {
    Devil {
        hp: self.x + n,
        weapon: None,
    }
}
```

...it is obvious that the `weapon`, which is the sole purpose of `Devil`'s lifetime parameter, is in no way related to the reference to `self`, so the lifetimes of `&self` and `Devil` should have *nothing to do with each other*.

This leads to problems later when the `Devil` is assigned an actual weapon, as we might want to give the `Devil` a `weapon` with a different lifetime, and there is no reason that we should not be able to do this.

Also, the current implementation of `transform` forbids the returned `Devil` from outliving the reference to `self`, and this need not be the case.

To fix the problem, explicitly annotate `transform` to make it clear that `&self` and the returned `Devil` have unrelated lifetimes:

```
fn transform<'a, 'b>(&'a self, n: i32) -> Devil<'b>
```

Comment: Thank you! It compiles after doing the same modification on the test code, and I start to understand why the problem exists. However, the real situation is that the `transform()` is a function provided as a third-party library(actually hyper::client::Client::get()). I'm still wondering why `transform_and_arm(self)` can't work. Since devil lives until line C, it won't outlive brace or Foo anyway, because the Foo is consumed after line C...

Comment: Another relevant observation is that uncommenting `devil.slay_the_world();` only won't cause a compile error, but uncommenting `devil.arm(buz);` then will. I'm just wanting to consume all the fields of Foo in `transform_and_arm(self)`.